# Error in selecting the range of columns in the same row

Tags: excel, vba

Its showing error in selecting a range of columns in the same row. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here. Part of my code looks like below

```
    If .Cells(i, "C") = "Major Bridge" Or .Cells(i, "C") = "Minor Bridge" Then
    ****Range("G"&i-1:"L"&i-1).Select****
     Selection.ClearContents
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range("G" & i-1 & ":L" & i-1).ClearContents
```

or

```
Range("G" & i-1, "L" & i-1).ClearContents
```

You might benefit from reading
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).